# Having Trouble Setting Image with Correct Dimensions Using AlamofireImage

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, alamofireimage

I have been using an `UIImageView` subclass, found [here](https://gist.github.com/algal/03e661630a6869c883d9d915d5ecccbc), to set asynchronously-downloaded images inside of `UITableViewCell`s, keeping the correct aspect ratio. That class follows:

```swift
internal final class ScaleAspectFitImageView: UIImageView {

    /// Constraint to maintain same aspect ratio as the image.
    private var aspectRatioConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? = nil

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    public override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    public override init(image: UIImage!) {
        super.init(image: image)
        setup()
    }

    public override init(image: UIImage!, highlightedImage: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image, highlightedImage: highlightedImage)
        setup()
    }

    override public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            print("\nUpdating aspect ratio constraints")
            updateAspectRatioConstraint()
            print("Updated aspect ratio constraints\n")
        }
    }

    private func setup() {
        contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        updateAspectRatioConstraint()
    }

    /// Removes any pre-existing aspect ratio constraint, and adds a new one based on the current image
    private func updateAspectRatioConstraint() {
        // Remove any existing aspect ratio constraint
        if let constraint = aspectRatioConstraint {
            removeConstraint(constraint)
        }
        aspectRatioConstraint = nil
        if let imageSize = image?.size, imageSize.height != 0 {
            let aspectRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
            let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: aspectRatio, constant: 0)
            addConstraint(constraint)
            aspectRatioConstraint = constraint
        }
    }

}
```

I am also using `AlamofireImage` to download the images inside of `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, which follows:

```swift
cell.embeddedImageImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
cell.embeddedImageImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2

let placeholderImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "postImagePlaceholder")

if let embeddedImageURL = message.mediaURL {
    let filter = AspectScaledToFitSizeFilter(size: cell.embeddedImageImageView.frame.size)
    cell.embeddedImageImageView.af_setImage(withURL: embeddedImageURL, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, filter: filter)
} else {
    cell.embeddedImageImageView.image = placeholderImage
}
```

However, when the images download, they are placed inside of the cell's `embeddedImageImageView`, resulting in incorrect sizes.

Following is a screenshot of my cells, where I have placed a red border around the `UIImageView`, which is the `ScaleAspectFitImageView` subclass.

[image: Screenshot of current image dimensions]

What am I doing incorrectly that is causing my images to not be sized properly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make your cell's image view a subclass of **ScaleAspectFitImageView** in the first place?

[image]

Running the subclass you posted causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS. So I deleted the **aspectRatioConstraint** property and their usage and ran your code, everything is working perfectly fine.

[image: ImageViews size themselves as expected]